# Second UIView Overlapped on First UIView when i change simulator at portrait to landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

Hi I am new for iOS and I am create two `UIviews` programmatically on my main `ViewController` and here I have added two button on my `UIviews` they are `Next` and `Back` buttons

Here when I click `Next` button I make to move first `UIview` to second `UIview` (like how we move one view controller to another view controller). When I click `Back` button I am pushing back to second `UIview` to first `UIview` using `UIview` animations

Here my main problem is: when I change first `UIview` orientation at portrait to landscape mode, second `UIview` is overlapped on my first `UIview`. That is my main issue and I am not understand why this problem is coming/ Please help me someone.

### My code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    UIView * MyFisrtView;
    UIView * MySecondView;

    UIButton * GoNext;
    UIButton * GoBack;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyFisrtView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    MyFisrtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    MyFisrtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MyFisrtView];

    MySecondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    MySecondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    MySecondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MySecondView];

    NSDictionary * HeaderDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(MyFisrtView,MySecondView);

    //Appliying Autolayouts for FirstView

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[MyFisrtView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[MyFisrtView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    //Appliying Autolayouts for SecondView

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[MySecondView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[MySecondView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];


    GoNext = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    GoNext.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 18);
    [GoNext setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [GoNext addTarget:self action:@selector(GoNext:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    GoNext.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [MyFisrtView addSubview:GoNext];

    GoBack = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    GoBack.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 18);
    [GoBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [GoBack addTarget:self action:@selector(GoBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    GoBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [MySecondView addSubview:GoBack];

    MyFisrtView.hidden = NO;
    MySecondView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)GoNext:(id)sender{

    MySecondView.hidden = NO;

    MySecondView.frame=CGRectMake(248, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // starting visible position

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

-(void)GoBack:(id)sender{

    MySecondView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // starting visible position

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(MyFisrtView.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: in your third constraint replace present constraint with H:[MyFisrtView]-0-[MySecondView]-0-|  and check

Comment: yes i tried same issues raising no change

Comment: i know that's must be constraint issue

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `screen size` changes from `landscape to portrait`. For example, in `portrait` mode height will be large and width will be small when compare it with `landscape` mode.

So, what you have to do is, you have to fix separate height and width for `portrait` and `landscape` and also change `x` and `y` position for different orientation.

And also, from your code I didn't see any change `orientation delegates`. If you want to fix your issue, you have to implement those `delegates`.

Comment: can you modified my code and suggest how can we do this please

Comment: Yeah! Just send me the device name you are working with.. I will update you with answer

Comment: and by the way i am using Auto-layouts here that's why my code suitable in all devices right Balaji Kondalrayal? ok i hope you give solution to this question

Comment: Auto layout should be disabled then only we can change the frame of views with respect to orientation. Your app will run in all devices even you deselect auto layout

Comment: how can we with out autolayouts can you update my code please

Answer (score 1):

First of all comment out your Constraints and make the modifications as below

```
@interface ViewController (){
    UIView * MyFisrtView;
    UIView * MySecondView;

    UIButton * GoNext;
    UIButton * GoBack;

    BOOL isSecondShown;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyFisrtView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    MyFisrtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    MyFisrtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MyFisrtView];

    MySecondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    MySecondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    MySecondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MySecondView];


    GoNext = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    GoNext.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 18);
    [GoNext setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [GoNext addTarget:self action:@selector(GoNext:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    GoNext.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [MyFisrtView addSubview:GoNext];

    GoBack = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    GoBack.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 18);
    [GoBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [GoBack addTarget:self action:@selector(GoBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    GoBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [MySecondView addSubview:GoBack];

//    MyFisrtView.hidden = NO;
//    MySecondView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if(isSecondShown){
    [MyFisrtView setFrame:CGRectMake(MySecondView.frame.origin.x - MySecondView.frame.size.width, MySecondView.frame.origin.y, MySecondView.frame.size.width, MySecondView.frame.size.height)];
    [MySecondView setFrame:self.view.frame];
    }
    else{
        [MyFisrtView setFrame:self.view.frame];
        [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
}

-(void)GoNext:(id)sender{

//    MySecondView.hidden = NO;

    MySecondView.frame=CGRectMake(248, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // starting visible position

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         isSecondShown = YES;
                     }];
}

-(void)GoBack:(id)sender{

//    MySecondView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // starting visible position

    [MyFisrtView setFrame:CGRectMake(MySecondView.frame.origin.x - MySecondView.frame.size.width, MySecondView.frame.origin.y, MySecondView.frame.size.width, MySecondView.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                             [MyFisrtView setFrame:self.view.frame];
                         }];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         isSecondShown = NO;
                     }];
}

@end
```

Comment: yes your code is work fine but why it's not possible using with Constraints

Comment: When you change orientation layout will be updated. Constraints define a relationship between two views, so whenever you are second screen and rotate the orientation then again you will see the first screen as layout update takes place. I think you need read more about constraints in apple docs to know how exactly they works. As a beginner you might be confused but you get to know things as you work on :)

Comment: Still things are possible with constraints, but every time you rotate you need to remove existing constraints programatically and add new constraints which is a bit complex. you can give it a shot to learn

Comment: harsha do you how to remove and add constraints

Comment: you can do that using for example `[MySecondView removeConstraints: MySecondView.constraints]` for any view you can do so. If this answer is working for you up vote so it might be useful for future